# How to get text on top of menu bar - java fx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to do something like this 
[Image to what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7cyA.png)

I have tried following this question [Text on java fx menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576445/text-on-java-fx-menu-bar) but nothing is working, I end up with this [my version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6jv0.png). I am also not sure how to make it responsive so if it's in a larger size it will change to suit that screen size. (New to JavaFX)

Here is the code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<!--<AnchorPane id="menu-bar-container" stylesheets="@TestCSS.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111">-->
    <AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" styleClass="menu-bar" id="menu-bar-container" stylesheets="@TestCSS.css">
    <MenuBar id="menu-bar" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0">
        <Menu text="File">
            <items>
                <MenuItem text="Close" />
            </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu text="Help">
            <items>
                <MenuItem text="About" />
            </items>
        </Menu>
    </MenuBar>
    <Label style="-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-text-fill: black; " text="Some text" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0" />
</AnchorPane>
```

My style code

```
    #menu-bar {
    -fx-padding: 0 ;
    -fx-background-color: transparent ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 ;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 ;
}

#menu-bar-container {
    -fx-padding: 0.0em 0.666667em 0.0em 0.666667em; /* 0 8 0 8 */
    -fx-background-color:
        linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-base,75%) 0%, -fx-outer-border 90%),
        linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-base,46.9%) 2%, derive(-fx-base,-2.1%) 95%);
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 1 0 1 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0, 0 ;
    -fx-background-color: red ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses a `StackPane` with a `MenuBar` and a `Label`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <StackPane>
               <children>
                  <MenuBar>
                    <menus>
                      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                        <items>
                          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                        </items>
                      </Menu>
                      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                        <items>
                          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                        </items>
                      </Menu>
                      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                        <items>
                          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                        </items>
                      </Menu>
                    </menus>
                  </MenuBar>
                  <Label fx:id="lblUsername" text="Label" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
                     <StackPane.margin>
                        <Insets right="10.0" />
                     </StackPane.margin>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </StackPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: green;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="258.0" layoutY="159.0" text="App Goes Here!" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <ToolBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <items>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Bread Crumb Bar usually goes here" />
              </items>
            </ToolBar>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to replace that other menubar to be a label so I can be able to change it, example put the user's name there or etc...

Comment: Also is it better to start every scene with an Anchor Pane?

Comment: You should be able to set the text of `Some Text` using `menuItem.setText()`. The key to layouts is figuring out how each layout node works. Pay attention to when and how the better/higher rated users of this site use layout nodes and read the javadocs.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks that solved my issue, how would you go on about when trying to design for responsive? (I just want to know before I put in a lot of time)

Comment: Most of the layouts I create, I start with an `AnchorPane` and then  `VBox`. The `VBox` fills the `AnchorPane`.
The `MenuBar` is at the top of the `VBox`, another `AnchorPane` in the center set to `alwaysGrow`, and a footer at the bottom using `BreadCrumbBar` by `ControlsFX`.

Comment: `HBox` and `VBox` are my bread and butter throughout the layout.

Comment: So the alwaysGrow does that extend what ever is in the AchorPane to grow as long as it fills the anchor pane then.

Comment: `alwaysGrow` is for the `VBox` it allows that center `AnchorPane` to fill the center. To extend nodes in an `AnchorPane` you have to use something like `AnchorPane.setTop(node, 0)`

Comment: The App section normally consists of `SplitPane`, `TabPane`, `TableView`, `ListView`, and lots of `HBox` and/or `VBox`.

Comment: I see, I will have to read more of it's java doc. The nodes part is a little confusing though